# What is the best way to encrypt/decrypt query string parameters in Java Spring Web MVC?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, encryption, servlet-filters

I have a Spring MVC web project already deployed on production and is up and running.
It has many HTML forms and many endpoints in the controller are of **GET** request having query string parameters.

For example:
**http://www.examplesite.com/user?userId=123**

We are using mysql database. In above example, the query string **userId**'s value **123** is the **primary key of mysql table**. As it is plain integer value, It could be altered by any user easily and he could see the data which he is not supposed to see.

I need to encrypt **123** to some random String (like **abcrtxjfojgo33joijo3** or something..).

The problem is that, project is already deployed and changing the query string parameters from Integer to String will need too many changes across my Views, controllers and even in Services and it is not at all feasible for me at this stage.

Is there any possible and reliable way in which I can get the Integer query Strings get encrypted before it is sent in View and again Decrypt it when I receive it in controller?

Note: This is not the duplicate question of "HOW TO ENCRYPT/DECRYPT QUERY STRING PARAMS?" question.

Please read my questions before flagging it as duplicate one.

Comment: *he could see the data which he is not supposed to see.*: only if your code fails to check permissions before displaying data. That's what you should do.

Comment: I considered this thing but you see, it would still be a lot of code that needs to be added just to check whether someone has required permissions to access resources or not.
And as I mentioned in my question, the project is already Live and we need to figure out something effective and quick (and encrypting query string is 1 way I think)

Comment: Why not encrypt it to another integer value?

Comment: Typically these problems are solved by using access token. These are secure and random keys generated per user and should be passed along with user id for ensuring that only the right user is accessing the data with its own key. Even if someone changes the user id, he cannot possibly fathom  the access token value (which is typically a 16 character random string)

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz Thats also possible. But what about the way to achieve it? I mean what could be the best thing to do in this case if we want to encrypt it to some random integer value? It'll ofcourse save us from changing Data Types in controllers/services but when do we encrypt it and decrypt it? 

Using Filters is an option but then it'd be overhead in every network request call

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - How does this work in case of HTML forms being submitted to Controllers? I think its not useful in my use-case. 

Suppose a controller has endpoint GET /user-details?id=<PRIMARY_KEY>

How do I make it sure with the help of access tokens that the above endpoint with id parameter is being called by authorized user only?

Like if you are logged-in to my site, you have an access token. If you now hit that above URL with your custom id in query string, how do I prevent you from accessing that data?

Comment: No, you don't need to encrypt/decrypt in a `Filter`. What you can do is to write utility methods that will encrypt and decrypt a given `Integer` value. And you can call these methods when you get a request in your controller. First thing you will be doing is to decrypt the `userId` that you will receive and then do whatever you want to do like reading the User from database etc.

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz umm makes sense...something I had in mind...
May not be the best thing/way to do but seems good for now. 

Any other better approaches are most welcome. Hope someone answers

Comment: @SumitBadaya, first of all, I'm curious to know that why do you need such kind of functionality? Let's suppose a `userId` is `123` and what would happen if he knows that `123` is my id? Can he abuse the system with that?

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz Problem is not with your ID 123 or whether you know its your ID.

I need to prevent YOU from seeing the data of ID 200 or any other user by just passing any random integer value in that query string. Coz you should not be able to see any other user's data, which at the moment, is being displayed just by changing query string values 


....
Makes sense?

Comment: @SumitBadaya Yes, that makes sense. So to completely protect this from happening you should either use a `UUID` or encrypted `String` value just like **abcrtxjfojgo33joijo3** which you've mentioned in your question. I know you will have to change your method and services but I think this is what you should be doing. And in my opinion, this is a best practice.

Comment: ***just** to check whether someone has required permissions*. Why **just**? Security and permissions in particular is one of the **most important** parts of the application.

Comment: And that's what brought me here to post a question about current project situation and security issue. @mentallurg

Comment: Obfuscating the data provides not a good security. How will user know what ID should it use? You will somehow provide this information to user, e.g. send per Email, Thus there will be risk that smb. else gets this info and uses this link. Instead, implement normal authentication and authorization.

Comment: **How will user know what ID should it use?** 
User doesn't need to know this. Users just need to navigate through Navigation Menu Links (some of which are based on logged-in user's ID as given in example link in my question)